# Story where immortal beings are trapped inside a planet?

Tags: story-identification

I remember reading a sci-fi novel where a community of immortal beings are trapped within the core of a planet, but the surface they are trapped on is expanding very slowly, so they just have to survive for a few hundred years until they can reach the planet's crust again.

Does anyone recognise this story? Trying to find the title.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is probably [Marrow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(novel)), by Robert Reid, an expansion of his earlier short story by the same name.

The plot takes place on a giant Jupiter-sized spaceship, built by an unknown race but crewed by a set of functionally immortal humans. Some of them discover a planet at the core of the ship, and are stranded there by some kind of ion storm. After hundreds of years of studying the patterns of the storms, they realise the planet is expanding. In a few thousand years they will be able to build a bridge back into the surrounding ship.

Comment: Ace thank you so much!