# Science fiction book based on a Jupiter-sized wandering/rogue planet?

Tags: story-identification, books

I read a book about 8-10 years ago (and at least one sequel) which was set on a wandering planet the size of Jupiter. Those who lived there lived under the surface in vast caverns and these inhabitants lived for hundreds (if not thousands of years). I distinctly remember one scene in which a bunch of inhabitants became hopelessly trapped in a hot, lava volcanic area for what I remember to be 2,000 - 20,000 years! I want to read these books again! Can anyone identify these please?

Comment: I answered this recently: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/story-where-immortal-beings-are-trapped-inside-a-planet/116405#116405

Comment: We can't close this as a dupe per our [story-id duplicate policy](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/7067/31936).

Comment: @DanielRoseman - If you post your answer here and it gets accepted we can then set it up as a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

Per [Daniel Roseman's comment](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/119764/im-trying-to-identify-a-science-fiction-book-based-on-a-jupiter-sized-wandering#comment292800_119764), since it's been 9 months and he hasn't posted it as an answer: **this sounds very much like [*Marrow*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Marrow_(novel)), a 2000 novel by Robert Reed.**

---

*at least one sequel*

> The sequel to *Marrow* is [*The Well of Stars*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Well_of_Stars) (2004).

*a wandering planet the size of Jupiter*

> When a jovian sized, artificially-created structure enters the galaxy, a society of technologically advanced humans (capable of interstellar flight and functionally immortal) are the first to intercept and investigate it.

*Those who lived there lived under the surface in vast caverns and these inhabitants lived for hundreds (if not thousands of years).*

> Finding it to be an intergalactic ship, they decide to convert it into a cruise ship, inviting alien races to join them in its massive, uncharted interior as it makes a slow circumnavigation of the Milky Way. After thousands of years, with over 200 billion creatures living in its upper levels ...

*I distinctly remember one scene in which a bunch of inhabitants became hopelessly trapped in a hot, lava volcanic area for what I remember to be 2,000 - 20,000 years!*

> ... a group of explorers discover a planet hidden in the core of the Great Ship. As they explore it, however, an ionic blast cuts them off from the rest of the ship and destroys much of their technology. Because this planet, Marrow, is slowly expanding, the explorers reason that a new bridge can be built in another 5,000 years. They thus begin a civilization on the surface of Marrow.